# Logback XML not being picked up

Tags: jboss, wildfly, redhat, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to implement `Logback` for an existing `EAP7.2` app.

```
JBoss EAP 7.2.8.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.27.Final-redhat-00001)
```

When I run `gradle clean build` it creates the proper log in the location and logs all of the test results. But when I deploy the app it's not using the `logback.xml` at all and the logs aren't created. Only the `server.log` is active when the app is deployed because it's the default jboss setup.

How do I implement logback so that the app knows to use it when deployed? I've checked the war the logback.xml gets created under the proper `WEB-INF/classes/`

**EAR build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3'
}
```

**jboss exclusions**

```
        <exclusions>
            <!-- don't want to integrate with server logging yet -->
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
        </exclusions>
```

**server.log**

```
2020-09-25 16:28:05,188 INFO  [stdout] (QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager) 16:28:05.187 [QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore - Lock 'STATE_ACCESS' given to: QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager
2020-09-25 16:28:05,188 INFO  [stdout] (QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager) 16:28:05.188 [QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is desired by: QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager
2020-09-25 16:28:05,189 INFO  [stdout] (QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager) 16:28:05.188 [QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is being obtained: QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager
2020-09-25 16:28:05,189 INFO  [stdout] (QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager) 16:28:05.189 [QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' given to: QuartzScheduler_AppScheduler-<server>11601051265073_ClusterManager
```

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${jboss.server.log.dir}/logs.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</FileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [username:%X{username}][%thread] %logger [%file:%line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    
    <logger name="org.quartz" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude logging subsystem in jboss-deployment-structure.xml and also  set org.jboss.logging.provider system property.

You can follow this Red Hat article on [steps to configure LogBack](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3602471) with JBoss EAP 7

Also have a look at various options of [configuring external logging](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/405893).